# Commit git to remote repository without cloning any local repository

Tags: git, github, github-api

My question is quite simple, however I don't find any answer on StackOverflow or elsewhere (except this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18187888/pushing-a-single-commit-to-the-git-remote-repository-without-history-or-merging) but without being answered):

Does anyone know a way to commit a GIT change "directly" to a remote repository (Github in my case) without cloning the repository in local and having to commit first to local repository then pushing to remote?

Commits will be performed programmatically from Python (by using simply GIT command lines).
Honestly I don't see the advantage (in my case) of having a separate server (for local repos) and keep huge git repository on it just to push them finally to Github.

Comment: you can do commit directly on Github using web interface: https://github.com/WGBH/pbucore/wiki/Contributing-to-the-project-through-Github-web-interface

Comment: As said in my question, commits will be performed "progrmmatically from Python engine"

Comment: AFAIK, Git just doesn't work that way. You can only push commits to a remote, the commit must be made to a clone. You can use --shallow* and --depth to minimise what's checked out. @barro32's answer is also a good approach. It should be quite easy to achieve this programatically.

Comment: Why do you have to have a "separate server for local repos"? You can clone on whatever environment the Python script is running and push directly to GitHub.

Comment: I said server only because the main application is running on a server. Users connect to that application and perform some changes on the data, then the application generates automatically a script from user changes then that script should be pushed to remote GIT repo. So keeping all scripts (which will be a big amount of files = huge storage needed) is useless in my point of view.

Answer (score 10):

You can clone the repo with `-n` to not checkout any files.
`--depth 1` will truncate the history of each file to their last commit

`git clone -n git://path/to/repo.git --depth 1`

`cd repo`

Checkout only the files you need to change for your commit

`git checkout HEAD file.ext`

Just be careful to only commit the file you're working on. If you do something like `git add .` you will be committing the deletion of all files you have not checked out!

Comment: In order to be able to checkout the file on the cloned repo, the file should be copied first in the cloned repo. This is exactly what I want to avoid. Tell me if I misunderstood your suggestion

Comment: @SachaShadkami, checking out a file is the copying itself (or overwriting if it already exists locally)...

Comment: For me, all my files are staged for deletion right after `git clone -n ...` so they would get deleted with `git commit` without even calling `git add .`. I solve it by calling `git reset HEAD` right after the `git clone -n ...`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create commits by using Git command line tools (Python or not doesn't matter) — those tools require a local repository and most of them require a local checkout (work tree).

You can [create commits using Github API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52941620/7976758) but this is much harder and you need completely different set of tools like [pygithub](/questions/tagged/pygithub) or any other Python Github API wrapper.